# Whats wrong in this(probablity)?

Tags: probability

Probability of getting $1$ in a fair die is $\frac{1}{6}$

and it should be same as

getting $1+$ not getting $2+$ not getting $3+$ not getting $4+$not getting $5+$ not getting $6$
(mutually exclusive right?)

which is $$\frac{1}{6}+\frac{5}{6}+\frac{5}{6}+\frac{5}{6}+\frac{5}{6}+\frac{5}{6}$$

why answers are different when in both cases we are finding probablity of getting $1$?

Comment: getting 1, not getting 2, not getting 3, not getting 4, not getting 5, and not getting 6 are not all mutually exclusive

Comment: For example, getting a 6 falls into the "not getting 2", "not getting 3", "not getting 4", and "not getting 5" situations.

Comment: And getting 1 fits into all of the situations {not getting 2,not getting 3,not getting 4,not getting 5,not getting 6}

Comment: probability of "not getting 2 " means getting "1 or 3 or 4 or 5 or 6"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Letting $1,2,3,4,5,$ and $6$ be the events of rolling a $1,2,3,4,5,$ and $6$ respectively, I believe what you want to find is

$$P(1 \cap 2^c \cap 3^c \cap 4^c \cap 5^c \cap 6^c)=P(1)=\frac{1}{6}$$

Answer (score 0):

Adding to [Remy's](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2705713/500125) answer, 
 P(getting 1) is not equal to 
P(getting 1) OR P(not getting 2) OR P(not getting 3) OR P(not getting 4) OR P(not getting 5) OR P(not getting 6).
 Only in this case where "OR" comes in probability of events we add as you've tried. i.e 
 P(1) + P(2') + P(3') + P(4') + P(5') + P(6')
**If A and B are mutually exclusive, then P(A or B) = P(A) + P(B)**

In general, two events A and B are called mutually exclusive events if the occurrence of any one of them excludes the occurrence of the other event, i.e., if they can not occur simultaneously. In this case getting "1" automatically excludes getting other numbers from "2" to "6".